# Smaller `\odot` for elementwise/pointwise product

Tags: math-operators, operator-space

I usually use `$\circ$` for elementwise/pointwise product of vectors/matrices/functions.

- I find `$\cdot$` unsuitable: it is often used for the dot product, so is ambiguous.
- `$f \circ g$` is also ambiguous when working with functions, since it can mean composition.
- The machine learning community seems to use `$\odot$` for this, and I think it makes the equations hard to read.

Compare the sizes of the other operators to `$\odot$`:

```
$$a + a - a * a \times a \div a \cdot a \circ a \odot a$$
```

I'd like to adjust `$\odot$` to take up roughly similar amounts of space and ink as `$+-*\times\div\circ\cdot$`, while also exactly matching their vertical centering and horizontal padding.

Bonus points if this adjustment does not require importing any new latex packages, so could be tossed into Markdown Latex in a pinch. So far I've found `\op{{}_{{}^{\text{$\odot$}}}}`, which looks horrific in code, but renders as `$a\op{{}_{{}^{\text{$\odot$}}}} b$`. It's close but doesn't get the write vertical centering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\circ` with `\cdot` in the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pdot}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\pdot@\relax}}
\newcommand{\pdot@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\circ$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\cdot$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x\pdot y$ (pdot)

$x\odot y$ (odot)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very beautiful in your rendering, but my PDF viewer does not always render the middle dot as centered (even using the default fonts). I expect this is because it's not a single glyph, whereas ☉ ... might be? I guess it will look very nice on high-DPI screens and in print.

Comment: @MRule Rasterizing problems at small resolutions. I don't think it can be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\scalerel`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand*{\pdot}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\boldsymbol\odot}{\circ}}}


\begin{document}

$x\pdot y$ (pdot)

$x\odot y$ (odot)

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT:** Using `\scalebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\centerodot}[1]{\boldsymbol{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{\odot}}}}}
\newcommand*{\pdot}[1][.5]{\mathbin{{\centerodot{#1}}}}


\begin{document}

$x\pdot y$ (pdot)

$x\odot y$ (odot)

\end{document}
```

The size of the `centered odot` can be adjusted by modifying the default scaling factor in the scalebox; .5 in this case.

[image]

Comment: very nice and the center dot stays centered when rasterized; but! It comes out as just slightly larger than $\circ$ for me, and also visible lower than it (default fonts). I'm guessing fiddling with `mbox` might be able to achieve a better match, similar to `@egreg`'s solution? This being a "professional" typesetting tool, it would be nice to get things to align *exactly*.

Comment: @Mrule Answer edited